# Custom OSX application icon

Tags: xcode, macos, icons

I've found the application executable created by Xcode, but it have the default icon.
Now I'd like to change it for my own image, a png 512x512 file.

But when I drag the file to "App icon" in Xcode, it appears an interrogation symbol, and the app is not created with the icon.

So what's wrong?

Comment: What kind of file do you have?

Comment: What do you mean? I said that is a 512x512 png.

Comment: Missed the png-part. Have you tried with an [icns-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format)?